# Setting up NTFS permissions on a Root folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm creating a script so lesser capable techs can quickly and easily setup server side folders. I've been able to create the folder, related AD security groups and started assigning permissions, but I got stuck when I had 1 security groups listed twice.

Basically I have a FolderA_Ro and FolderA_RW groups with FolderA_RW being listed twice.

FolderA_RW - SPECIAL - Traversal, List folder, Read attributes, Read extended attributes, Create files, Create folders, Read permissions - This folder only

FolderA_RW - Modify - Subfolders and files only

This prevents users from renaming the folder and anything else they might do that can't be predicted. Yes, I've had a lot of issues with these kinds of things happening.

I can add the first one without issue, but I can't seem to get it to add the second. Any ideas? Here's my code...

```
$RFolder = read-host "folder name"
```

$path = "C:$($RFolder)"

<# Remove all NTFS permissions #>

```
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$acl.Access | %{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
Set-Acl $path $acl
```

<# Remove inheritence #>

```
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

<# Assign NTFS permissions #>

```
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("PMGTINC\Domain Users","Delete, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership", "None", "None", "Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("PMGTINC\SEC_$($RFolder)_Ro","ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("PMGTINC\SEC_$($RFolder)_RW","CreateFiles,AppendData,ReadAndExecute", "None", "None", "Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("PMGTINC\SEC_$($RFolder)_RW","Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors, it simply applies only 1 of the 2 access rules that have the same Security group name.  I feel that the 2nd rule needs to be Add-Acl instead of Set-Acl, but this command doesn't exist.

Comment: Created and answer with some modifications of your script, try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your script to something like this:

```
$RFolder = read-host "folder name"

#Define some variables
$path = "C:\$($RFolder)"
$domain="PMGTINC"
$RoGroup="$domain\SEC_$($RFolder)_Ro"
$RWGroup="$domain\SEC_$($RFolder)_RW"


<# Remove all NTFS permissions #>
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$acl.Access | %{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
Set-Acl $path $acl

<# Remove inheritence #>
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl

<# Assign NTFS permissions #>
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$domain\Domain Users","Delete, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership", "None", "None", "Deny")
#Append the AccessRule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule( $AccessRule )
#Push settings
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$RoGroup","ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
#Append the AccessRule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule( $AccessRule )
#Push settings
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$RWGroup","CreateFiles,AppendData,ReadAndExecute", "None", "None", "Allow")
#Append the AccessRule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule( $AccessRule )
#Push settings
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$RWGroup","Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
#Append the AccessRule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule( $AccessRule )
#Push settings
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $path
```

Comment: Sadly, the same end result. The 1st RW permissions is set, then is overwritten when the 2nd RW permission is set.